# python Regex- get match based on condition

Tags: python, regex

I have the below text string

```
text = "\n1.2.2. ROAD LOAD PARAMETERS \nf0 \n227.4 \nf1 (N/(km/h)) \n0.149"
```

I am trying to write a regex match pattern to get values (consecutive 2 values) that follows `'1.2.2. ROAD LOAD PARAMETERS'`.

Expected output:

```
1.2.2. ROAD LOAD PARAMETERS : f0 227.4 # (only 2 values after the match)
```

Tried the below regex:

```
ec = re.search(r'(1.2.2. ROAD LOAD PARAMETERS)\s*(.+)', text)

ec.groups()
```

which gives me the following

```
('1.2.2. ROAD LOAD PARAMETERS', 'f0 ')
```

Comment: Maybe `m = re.search(r'\b(1.2.2. ROAD LOAD PARAMETERS).*((?:\n.*){2})', text)` and then `if m: print(f"{m.group(1)} : {m.group(2).replace(chr(10), '')}")`? See https://ideone.com/2pT9Hg

Comment: all the newline characters are fouling your regex. Try removing all the newline first with `clean_text = text.replace('\n', ' ')` From there it's trivial to split the string by fields and pull whatever you want.

Comment: great!this works. is it possible to get the output into a dictionary? @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Like  https://ideone.com/9v8Ncj ? I posted [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68035866/3832970).

Answer (score 1):

If the `1.2.2. ROAD LOAD PARAMETERS` is always fixed you can use this:

```py
ec = re.search(r'(1.2.2. ROAD LOAD PARAMETERS)\s+(\w+)\s+([\w\.]+)', text)
```

I replaced the `.+` with `\w+` in the first case to prevent matching the space, and also used `[\w\.]+` in the second case because you have alphanumerical plus a `.`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `str.split()` method:

```
import re

text = "\n1.2.2. ROAD LOAD PARAMETERS \nf0 \n227.4 \nf1 (N/(km/h)) \n0.149"

i = "1.2.2. ROAD LOAD PARAMETERS"

val1, val2 = text[text.index(i) + len(i):].split()[:2]
print(i, ":", val1, val2)
```

Output:

```
1.2.2. ROAD LOAD PARAMETERS : f0 227.4
```

Answer (score 1):

You need two of the `\s*(.+)` if you want to match two numbers.
Using

```
ec = re.search(r'(1.2.2. ROAD LOAD PARAMETERS)\s*(.+)\s*(.)', text)
```

gives you

```
('1.2.2. ROAD LOAD PARAMETERS', 'f0 ', '227.4 ')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
import re
text="\n1.2.2. ROAD LOAD PARAMETERS \nf0 \n227.4 \nf1 (N/(km/h)) \n0.149"
m = re.search(r'\b(1\.2\.2\. ROAD LOAD PARAMETERS).*((?:\n.*){2})', text)
d = {}
if m:
    d[m.group(1).strip()] = m.group(2).replace('\n', '').strip()

print(d)
## => {'1.2.2. ROAD LOAD PARAMETERS': 'f0 227.4'}
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/9v8Ncj).

The `\b(1\.2\.2\. ROAD LOAD PARAMETERS).*((?:\n.*){2})` regex matches

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(1\.2\.2\. ROAD LOAD PARAMETERS)` - Group 1: a fixed string
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `((?:\n.*){2})` - Group 2: two occurrences of a line feed char followed with any zero or more chars (two lines after the line containing `1.2.2. ROAD LOAD PARAMETERS`).

When building the dictionary you need to remove all line feeds from Group 2.